# apache RewriteRule not working

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have this url http://www.example.com/Courses/get/38789/my-course, i added this rule to the .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/Courses/get
RewriteRule ^Courses/get/(.*)/(.*)$ course-$1-$2 [R=301,L]
```

but when i go to http://www.example.com/Courses/get/38789/my-course nothing happens, i stay on the same page, there is no redirect.

p.s the link is just an example not the actual link

Comment: Is this complete .htaccess? Where is this .htaccess located?

Comment: @anubhava it is in the root document public_html

Comment: Is `/Courses/` a real directory?

Comment: @anubhava no it is not

Comment: Then how is this URL being handled? Isn't there some CMS/PHP controller in place here?

Comment: Verify whether your `.htaccess` is enabled or not, by putting same garbage (random) text on top of your `.htaccess` and see if it generates 500 (internal server) error or not when you visit your page in browser?

Answer (score 0):

A more efficient method would be to use the following:

```
RewriteRule ^Courses/get/(\d+)/([^/]+)/?$ /course-$1-$2 [R=301,L]
```

Now, keep in mind that this rule should come before any rules that may rewrite the request to, say, an `index.php` file. This would be naturally true if the code you posted in your question was all of your code. If not, please post your entire `.htaccess` file so we can be sure it is being placed in the right location.

Be sure the `mod_rewrite` is turned on, and the you have set `AllowOverride All` in your virtual host/Apache site configuration. If you're running on a shared production server, this would not apply to you.

*Side note:* Whilst it does work, you need not use `RewriteEngine on` twice - only once at the beginning of your file will suffice. You also do not need `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/Courses/get` - it is essentially redundant as you are already using an expression to test against the request.